# Can I refer to the positional arguments of $call by name instead?

Tags: makefile

It's very useful to be able to define families of rules via $(eval $(call )), like so:

```
define SIMPLE_TEMPLATE
  foo_$(1):
        echo foo $(1)
endef

$(foreach _,A B C,$(eval $(call SIMPLE_TEMPLATE,$_)))
```

This creates the targets `foo_A`, `foo_B`, and `foo_C`.  In a more complex template, it could be nice to refer to the argument to call by a name; i.e. `$(message)` rather than `$(1)`.  Something like this:

```
define SIMPLE_TEMPLATE
  MSG := $1
  foo_$(MSG):
        echo foo $(MSG)
endef

$(foreach _,A B C,$(eval $(call SIMPLE_TEMPLATE,$_)))
```

That *almost* works.  `foo_A` and `foo_B` work as expected but `foo_C` does not.  Interestingly, changing `A B C` to `A B C D` causes target `foo_C` to start working.  Here is how I understand what's going on: each pass through `eval` assigns a value to `$(MSG)`, but that assignment is not perceived until the *next* `eval` call.  Again, this does appear to work, if you append the extra pass through the loop.  But it feels wrong.  Is there a "correct" way to do this - and without having to do the extra-pass hack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make variable definitions and make functions are recursively expanded at different possible times, depending on the way they are defined (`A := ...` or `A = ...`) and where (in targets, pre-requisites, recipes...). [This section of GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reading-Makefiles) briefly explains this.

I see 2 different problems with your second Makefile:

1. The `$(MSG)` in your `SIMPLE_TEMPLATE` is expanded during expansion of the `$(foreach _,A B C,...`, not during the normal parsing of the result as make syntax. Let's look at this step-by step:

   - Expansion of the `foreach`:

     ```
     $(eval $(call SIMPLE_TEMPLATE,A)))
     $(eval $(call SIMPLE_TEMPLATE,B)))
     $(eval $(call SIMPLE_TEMPLATE,C)))
     ```
   - The expansion of the `eval` is special, it expands its parameter and instantiates it as a make construct. So, to understand, we must expand the `call` first. Each substitutes the `$(1)` in the definition of `SIMPLE_TEMPLATE`. What is passed to the first `eval`, for instance, is:

     ```
     MSG := A
     foo_$(MSG):
         echo foo $(MSG)
     ```
   - But, the expansion of the `eval` parameter continues until there is nothing left to expand. The references to `MSG`, which is not yet defined, are replaced by the empty string and the make constructs that are finally instantiated are:

     ```
     MSG := A
     foo_:
         echo foo
     ```

   with one (invisible) space at the end of `echo foo`. As any make construct they are expanded in turn but this does not change anything because there is nothing else to expand. During the expansion of the second `eval`, this time, `MSG` has value `A`, thanks to the first one. So, the second `eval` receives:

   ```
       MSG := B
       foo_$(MSG)       
           echo foo $(MSG)
   ```

   from `call`, expands it as:

   ```
       MSG := B
       foo_A       
           echo foo A
   ```

   and instantiates it as make constructs. These make constructs are expanded once more (as any other make constructs) but it does not change anything any more. Similarly, the third `eval` instantiates:

   ```
       MSG := C
       foo_B       
           echo foo B
   ```

   So, all in all, what will be instantiated as make constructs is:

   ```
   MSG := A
   foo_:
       echo foo 

   MSG := B
   foo_A:
       echo foo A

   MSG := C
   foo_B:
       echo foo B
   ```

   And you do not have any `foo_C` target (but you have an unwanted `foo_` target...)

   To escape the first and too early expansion of `$(MSG)` during the expansion of `$(foreach...` you can double the `$` signs:

   ```
   define SIMPLE_TEMPLATE
       MSG := $(1)
       foo_$$(MSG):
           echo foo $$(MSG)
   endef
   ```

   If we run this step-by-step, the first `call` will pass:

   ```
   MSG := A
   foo_$$(MSG):
       echo foo $$(MSG)
   ```

   to the first `eval`, which will expand it as:

   ```
   MSG := A
   foo_$(MSG):
       echo foo $(MSG)
   ```

   (eating one `$` per `$$`) and instantiate it as make constructs. These new make constructs will also be expanded, as any other make construct, which will give:

   ```
   MSG := A
   foo_A:
       echo foo $(MSG)
   ```

   (the `$(MSG)` in the recipe is not expanded yet because, in recipes, the expansion is deferred to the second phase and happens only when the recipe is selected for execution). After first expansion of the `$(foreach _,A B C,...` what you have is thus:

   ```
   MSG := A
   foo_A:
       echo foo $(MSG)

   MSG := B
   foo_B:
       echo foo $(MSG)

   MSG := C
   foo_C:
       echo foo $(MSG)
   ```

   But here, you hit the second problem:
2. Your different rules share the same `MSG` make variable. After the first phase its value is thus resolved as `C` and what you have is equivalent to:

   ```
   MSG := C
   foo_A:
       echo foo $(MSG)
   foo_B:
       echo foo $(MSG)
   foo_C:
       echo foo $(MSG)
   ```

   The result will be:

   ```
   $ make foo_A foo_B foo_C
   echo foo C
   foo C
   echo foo C
   foo C
   echo foo C
   foo C
   ```

   Probably not what you want. Note that even with a recursively expanded variable (`MSG = ...`), it would be the same.

To solve this second problem you could use the same make variable name for all targets but assign it target-specific values, like in:

```
define SIMPLE_TEMPLATE
    foo_$(1): MSG := $(1)
    foo_$(1):
        echo foo $$(MSG)
endef
```

(note the `$$` in the recipe) which expands as:

```
foo_A: MSG := A
foo_A:
    echo foo $(MSG)
...
```

Or, maybe, use different, constructed, variable names:

```
define SIMPLE_TEMPLATE
    MSG_$(1) := $(1)
    foo_$(1):
        echo foo $$(MSG_$(1))
endef
```

which expands as:

```
MSG_A := A
foo_A:
    echo foo $(MSG_A)
...
```

Both finally run as:

```
$ make foo_A foo_B foo_C
echo foo A
foo A
echo foo B
foo B
echo foo C
foo C
```

Probably closer to what you expected.