# Dynamically adding all apk's inside directory to AOSP system image

Tags: android, makefile, gnu-make, android-source

I'm having trouble adding a set of prebuilt apk's to my custom build of AOSP. What I am trying to accomplish is to allow developers of these apps to simply drop them in a directory under source control and the next CI build of the image will just include those applications. I have tried this using the code below to add all apks inside the `included_apks` directory but it's not working as expected.

```
define add_included_apks

    include $(CLEAR_VARS)

    LOCAL_MODULE := $(1:included_apks/%.apk=%)
    LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := eng userdebug
    LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
    LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $1
    LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := PRESIGNED

    include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
endef

APKS := $(call find-subdir-subdir-files, included_apks, '*.apk')
$(foreach item, $(APKS), $(eval $(call add_included_apks, $(item))))
```

The problem with this approach seems to be inside the `add_included_apks` function and how it is evaluated. When I print out `$(1:included_apks/%.apk=%)` it's the correct value but if I print out `LOCAL_MODULE` it's the last value set on it before this loop even though I'm calling `include $(CLEAR_VARS)`. And in the end the module is not included in the system image. Am I misunderstanding how a `foreach` call works in a make file?

**Edit Answer is correct, but the real AOSP bug is this:**

The `LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := eng userdebug` should be `LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := eng debug` to be included in a userdebug build variant. The make syntax was correct for what I was attempting to do.

Comment: To understand your problem you can read my recent answers to two similar questions: [Can I refer to the positional arguments of $call by name instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45426468/can-i-refer-to-the-positional-arguments-of-call-by-name-instead) and [Target wildcards in a shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45459103/target-wildcards-in-a-shell-command).

Comment: Thanks @RenaudPacalet, I'll take a look

Comment: @RenaudPacalet @Bobbake4 is it really the preferred way to "call" make submodules by `include`? I can fancy a thousand ways how this backfires on you, especially for build scripts which are stateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to print inside a define like that you have to escape the $ with another $.

```
define add_included_apks

    include $(CLEAR_VARS)

    LOCAL_MODULE := $(1:included_apks/%.apk=%)
    $$(error $$(LOCAL_MODULE))
    LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := eng userdebug
    LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
    LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $1
    LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := PRESIGNED

    include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
endef
```

Comment: You are correct! And after doing that it is printing what I was expecting. So for anyone coming to this question, the actual error is the `LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := eng userdebug` as it should be `LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := eng debug` to be included in a `userdebug` build variant. The make syntax was correct for what I was attempting to do. Thanks @maschall

Answer (score 0):

`'LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := eng debug'` will not include this in user builds, but eng and userdebug. If you want to have it included in user builds. It has to be `'optional'` and your `device/.../BoardConfig.mk` has to add those into:

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += your_local_module1 \
                your_local_module2 end so on...
```